# Click on link in main profile and automatically open in browser in work profile

Tags: vpn, work-profiles

I use [TrackerControl](https://trackercontrol.org/) and [Nebulo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frostnerd.smokescreen&hl=en&gl=US) with nearly all my apps in my main profile. I use [Shelter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.typeblog.shelter&hl=en_IE) which leverages the “Work Profile” feature of Android to provide an isolated space. In that isolated space I have my browsers and a VPN. Is there a way to automatically open links from apps in my main profile in my browser in the work profile? I can manually copy the link and open it in the browser but it's tedious. I already tried apps like "[Open Links With](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tasomaniac.openwith&hl=en_US&gl=US)" but it didn't work.

Example current behavior: Someone sends me a link to a website over a messenger (which is installed in my main profile), I click on it and it opens in the browser in my main profile.

Example wanted behavior: Someone sends me a link to a website over a messenger (which is installed in my main profile), I click on it and it automatically opens in the browser in my isolated work profile.

Thanks!

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles#prevent_failed_intents) the entity who manages the work profile (usually in a corporate environment some admin) can configure what Intents can pass from one profile to another (app-to-app communication bases on Intents). I am not sure how Shelter creates the work profile but I would assume that Shelter has the power to configure or implement this.